# Can I use Apps Script to create a date picker in a Docs document?

Tags: google-apps-script, datepicker

I'm creating a text document in Docs that will have different information for every user, and I'm trying to implement a date picker that will change the text in a few different places in the doc. I've only found information for Sheets or Forms.

I've gotten as far as a user prompt and have tried instantiating the datepicker Card class within it, but no dice.

Does anyone know if it's even possible in Docs?

Here's my useless code I basically purloined from the Apps Script samples lest anyone think I'm trying to solicit free coding:

```
function onOpen(e){
var dateTimePicker = CardService.newDatePicker()
    .setTitle("Enter appointment date.")
    .setFieldName("date_field")
    // Set default value as Jan 1, 2018 UTC. Either a number or string is acceptable.
    .setValueInMsSinceEpoch(1514775600)
    .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName("handleDateTimeChange"));
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
var result = ui.prompt(dateTimePicker);        
}
```

Comment: CardService is only applicable to Workspace Add-ons. The DocumentApp.getUI() method is limited to Editor Add-ons. [Check out the documentation to learn more](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/overview).

Comment: You could build a custom dialog with HtmlService